# How to perform 3D Reconstruction using ARCore?

Tags: point-clouds, arcore, 3d-reconstruction

I was trying to perform 3D Reconstruction from the point cloud being obtained from ARCore. However, The point cloud I was able to obtain using ARCore was not accurate or dense enough to perform 3D Reconstruction. Specifically, Points that were supposed to be on the same surface were off by a few miilimeteres due to which the surface looked as if it had a thickness.

Am I isolating the point cloud correctly or is it a limitation of ARCore ?
What should be the standard approach towards isolating the point cloud and for 3D Reconstruction ?

I am attaching below the point cloud obtained from a laptop.
( The file is in the .PLY format. The file can be viewed on  [https://sketchfab.com/](http://Sketchfab) ,[http://www.meshlab.net/](http://Meshlab) or any other software capable of rendering 3D models.)

The Keyboard and the screen of the laptop here look as if they have a thickness, although all the points were supposed to be at the same depth.

Please have a look at the point cloud and guide me as to what is going wrong here, since I have been stuck at it for quite some time now.

Thank you

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/18KMchFgYd8KOcyi8hPpB5yEfbnJ6DxmR/view?usp=sharing](http://Laptop)

Comment: It depends on how long you had to move around the laptop but to be fair, the result looks really impressive from a technical point of view, given that ARCore seems to do just simple point tracking. I don't think that you did anything fundamentally wrong. P.S.: Perfect that you included the point cloud, but maybe also include a screenshot from the point cloud in the question to give instant insight into the problem without the need of installing a viewer.

Comment: Could you include the code for the PLY export? Maybe there is an error there anyways